# What is the way to access IFrame's element using Prototype $ method

Tags: javascript, iframe, prototypejs

Using prototype js library I can access elements by using `$(elementID)`. I can access the element in an Iframe by

```
$('iframeID').contentWindow.document.getElementById('ID of element inside Iframe').
```

I would like to use the same dollar method for my Iframe to access elements in Iframe. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are eager to know the method, you can visit the link (after searching I got the link)

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/146705

and for the demo yo can visit here

http://sandbox.equawire.com/stackoverflow/DollarIFrame3.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could alias calling that `iframe` with something like:

```
var $IFRAME = function (id){
    return $('iframeID').contentWindow.document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Then, say you wanted to get the innerHTML of an element in that frame with id 'p1' you could do:

```
var x = $IFRAME('p1').innerHTML;
alert(x);
```

Or to manipulate it, for example hide it, you'd do:

```
$IFRAME('p1').hide();
```

The `$IFRAME` name for the function is arbitrary on my part, you could call it `getElementInsideIFrameID` or whatever appeals to you.

Comment: For example,$IFRAME('p1').hide(); does not work whereas, Element.hide($IFRAME('p1')) will work.

What I would like to have that is extending the element inside IFrame to have the same functionality which prototype js does.

Comment: Adding prototype.js to the "src" of Iframe makes it functional i.e.$IFRAME('p1').hide() works. I have tested it IE and FF. However, if the src IFrame doesnot have prototype.js, it does not work. How this can be achieve without adding prototype.js?

Comment: In my testing with the latest version of Prototype, locally, calling $IFRAME('p1').hide(); worked for me from inside the iframe containing page. Perhaps set up a test page online and we can get a closer look at what might be happening.

Comment: I have added a test at http://amar-desh.net/stackoverflow/DollarIframe.aspx Please check it.

Comment: I tried at your site but in my Browser IE8, it made error. However, I will make another page in which srcFrame having prototype.js and let me show you that worked for $Iframe('id').hide()

Comment: Setup another test http://amar-desh.net/stackoverflow/DollarIframe2.aspx where prototype.js also included in the iFrame src file.

Thanks.

Comment: At the moment I don't have IE8 to test with. What is the error?

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.4; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 28 Jan 2010 20:44:53 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 15
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://lab.artlung.com/change-content-in-iframe-with-prototype/?fbc_channel=1

Comment: One thing, I had Prototype being pulled from another domain, I've also changed the code somewhat. Now my example works in both Firefox and Safari. Does it do any better in MSIE?

Comment: Yes, it works by using Elemnet.method not using $('id').method()
which I told in my earlier post ...probably you miss that point ...
"For example,$IFRAME('p1').hide(); does not work whereas, Element.hide($IFRAME('p1')) will work. What I would like to have that is extending the element inside IFrame to have the same functionality which prototype js does. – Hoque Jan 25 at 3:06 "

Comment: Sorry I could not help you. Try the Prototype forums -- several options listed here: http://www.prototypejs.org/discuss

Comment: One of my friend has shared the following code and it works like a charm.
// Extend prototype's Method avaialble for IFrame 
    Prototype.extendFrame = function(element) {
        element = $(element);
        for (var m in Element.Methods) {
            if (Object.isFunction(Element.Methods[m])) {
                element.contentWindow.Element.prototype[m] =
                Element.Methods[m].methodize();
            }
        }
    }

My friend could not tell me the source of the code, but it helps me a lot.

Thanks to Artlung for his worthy time and thanks to my friend also.